# How can I import a node module into my backbone.js app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm trying to wrap my head around node.js modules, require, and how to use modules in a backbone.js app.

Right now I am using an express server which starts off with the code:

```
var express = require('express'),
http = require('http'),
config = require("./config"),
oauth = require("oauth"),
bcrypt = require("bcrypt"),
sqlite = require("sqlite3"),
_ = require("underscore"),
exec = require('child_process').exec,


app = express(),
server = http.createServer(app).listen( process.env.PORT || config.port);
```

and then I have a router.js file that defines ALL views and models.

**config.js** file that looks like this:

```
require.config({

baseUrl: '/',

paths: {
    'util'                : 'assets/lib/util',
    'jquery'              : 'assets/lib/jquery',
    'underscore'          : 'assets/lib/underscore',         
    'backbone'            : 'assets/lib/backbone'
},

shim: {
    'underscore'          : { exports  : '_' },
    'backbone'            : { deps : ['underscore', 'jquery'], exports : 'Backbone' },
    'bootstrap'           : { deps : ['jquery'], exports : 'Bootstrap' },
    'parsley'             : { deps: ['jquery'] },
    'socket'              : { deps : ['underscore', 'jquery'], exports : 'socket' }
}

});

require(['main']);
```

**My router.js** file starts off like this (I took out a bunch of code)

```
define(['app','jquery','underscore','backbone',], function(app, $, _, Backbone){

var WebRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

  routes: {
    "":     "index"
  },

  initialize: function(options) {

  }

return WebRouter;
});
```

and I'll just throw in my **main.js** file for good measure

```
require([
"app",
"router",
"models/SettingsModel"
],
function(app, WebRouter, SettingsModel) {

// Just use GET and POST to support all browsers
Backbone.emulateHTTP = true;

app.router = new WebRouter();

Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true, root: app.root });
```

});

Alright now here comes the tricky part. I want to use a node module, specifically the twitter-js-client module found at https://github.com/BoyCook/TwitterJSClient

so in my TwitterView.js, I can run the following code:

```
var twitter = new Twitter(config);
```

steps I've tried

- putting twitter-js-client in my package.json, running npm install, it installs fine but I don't know how to access the module
- manually running npm install twitter-js-client, can't run it for reasons above
- manually linking the keyword "twitter" to the Twitter.js file of npm module

  - this works, but then I get an error such as "node module oauth is not loaded yet use _. require for context"
  - I notice in the twitter.js file, it is requiring a number of packages including oauth

I am somewhat new to Node/backbone, and I'm looking for clarification of how Node,Require and Backbone all work with eachother. If anyone has any tips or constructive criticism on how to structure this app, I would greatly appreciate it. And if there are any solutions to loading the NPM module within a backbone view, I would be very grateful. Do I need a package manager like bower? I have no problems with Jquery, and underscore, but I can't seem to load this npm module.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [browserify](http://browserify.org/).

- Write you client side scripts with require statements.

  ```
  var Twitter = require('twitter').Twitter;
  ```
- run browserify against your scripts to generate a single bundle.js file
- include the resulting file on your page.

  ```
  <script src="bundle.js"></script>
  ```

Comment: I really appreciate this suggestion but I am still stuck.

the node module has a file called index.js which links to the Twitter.js which requires Oauth and qs

I tried browserify /node_modules/twitter-js-client/index.js -o bundle.js

but I am getting a "oauth" is not loaded yet for context

Comment: do you recommend which file I should add the Twitter object?